# Selecting the right algorithm for match probability prediction

Tags: machine-learning, classification, probability, scoring, azure-ml

Looking for assistance kick-starting a new machine learning scenario. In this case I need to pair one entity (ex. person) with a group of entities (ex. other people) given a history of matching patterns over time.

For example: Assume we have people who like other people with a combination of traits such as height, weight, education level, etc... This notation of 'like' is bi-directional when calculating probabilities. When a new person arrives I'd like to isolate a group of people (ranked by probability) to recommend them too.

In this case the input would be a single person with all their traits and the output would be a list of people with ranked probabilities of matching. There seems to be two main sets of data

- Known people
- Traits known people have liked or not with the traits of people they have liked or not

I am relatively new so not sure which types of training model to use. For example, is this something that can be accomplished most reasonable with a linear regression model, binary classification, boost-tree's, matchbox, etc, etc, etc..? Possibly I need a combination.

I am using the Azure Machine Learning studio which has lots of options but I am just not sure where to start in this scenario. Any suggestions or pointers would be appreciated in helping

Comment: What are your "history of matching patterns" like?

Answer (score 1):

It seems a variant of Movie Recommendation problem. Take Netflix for example, they have  user ratings for different type of movies; in your case users are telling what attributes they like. When a new user joins and rates the things he/she likes, you will find the people with similar interests, again with Netflix analogy it means recommending movies based on people with same tastes as the new user.

Read on [Collaborative filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering), which is used for building recommendation systems. The reason I drew the Netflix/Movie Recommendation analogy is because you can find a lot of literature on it.